# Session variable not getting updated during session in django

Tags: html, django

I'm new to web development and trying to create an auction website as a course project.
I'm trying to create a user-specific watchlist. It's able to add a product to the watchlist but when I go to delete an item from the watchlist it doesn't get deleted until I log out and log in again. Here is my code:

views.py:

```
def watchlist(request, item_id=None):
    if request.method == "POST":   
         for item in request.session["watchlist"]:
            if item["id"] == item_id:
                ind = request.session["watchlist"].index(item)
                modified = request.session["watchlist"][:ind] + 
                           request.session["watchlist"][ind + 1:]
                request.session["watchlist"] = modified
                break
    data = request.session["watchlist"]
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
        "data": data
    })
```

watchlist.html:

```
    {% block body %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2>Watchlist</h2>
        <ol>
            {% for item in data %}
            <li>
                <div style="display: flex;">
                    <div>
                        <img src="{{ item.image_url }}" alt="No image">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="{% url 'listing' item.id %}"><h4>{{ item.title }}</h4></a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Current Price: {{ item.current_price }}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <form action="{% url 'watchlist_del' item.id %}" action="post">
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
            </li>
            {% empty %}
            <h1>No items in watchlist</h1>
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

I checked session data through Django-admin and found that even after deleting an item, its data was not deleted from `request.session["watchlist"]`. It only gets updated after I log in and log out again.

I was able to fix the issue by replacing the form in watchlist.html with an `<a>` tag.

watchlist.html:

```
<div>
    <a href="{% url 'watchlist_del' item.id %}">Delete from watchlist</a>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def watchlist(request, item_id=None):
    if item_id is not None:   
        for item in request.session["watchlist"]:
            if item["id"] == item_id:
                ind = request.session["watchlist"].index(item)
                modified = request.session["watchlist"][:ind] + request.session["watchlist"][ind + 1:]
                request.session["watchlist"] = modified
                break
    data = request.session["watchlist"]
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
        "data": data
    })
```

but I was still wondering why there was a problem. Was there a problem with the post request? Please clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should specify `post` as [**`method=…`** attribute <sup>[mdn-doc]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method), not as [**`action=…`** attribute <sup>[mdn-doc]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action), and will requires a CSRF-token, so:

```
<form action="{% url 'watchlist_del' item.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Your view logic can be simplified with list comprehension:

```
def watchlist(request, item_id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['watchlist'] = [
            item for item in request.session['watchlist'] if item['id'] != item_id
        ]
    data = request.session['watchlist']
    return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', {'data': data})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Answer (score 0):

force update session after every update

```
 # Set session as modified to force data updates/cookie to be saved.
  request.session.modified = True
```

Comment: This is not the issue here: the value in the dictionary is a *new* object, so Django can detect that automatically. `request.session.mofied` is only necessary if you *modify* the object itself, so not a reference to another/new object.